# More readable way to extract keys of a type, where the types of the values for said key conform to an interface?

Tags: typescript

My app has a bunch of services at the boundary between the front-end and back-end that are called over Electron IPC using string names. To aid typechecking and editor support, I have an interface which maps service names to the interface type:

```
interface IFooService {
    aaa(): void;
    search(query: string): any;
}

interface IBarService {
    bbb(): void;
}

interface IAllServices {
    foo: IFooService,
    bar: IBarService,
}
```

On the front-end there's a generic search component that can search any of the services, and I was trying to get rid of the `any` type of the input property used to set which service to call.

For this I need to extract all keys on `IAllServices`, where the type of the key's value has a `search` method, into a type `SearchableServiceKey`. I.e. in the above example, `IFooService` has it, and `IBarService` does not, so I want the extracted type to be equivalent to `type SearchableServiceKey = 'foo'`.

The point of the exercise being that the type checker doesn't accept this:

```
function search(services: IAllServices, service: string, query: string) {
    services[service].search(query);
}
```

because `services[service]` only has the empty intersection of the keys of `IFooService` and `IBarService`; but should accept this:

```
function search(services: IAllServices, service: SearchableServiceKey, query: string) {
    services[service].search(query);
}
```

---

I managed to get this working using this construction:

```
type ServiceKey = keyof IAllServices;

interface ISearchable {
    search(query: string): any;
}

type IsSearchable<SK extends ServiceKey> = IAllServices[SK] extends ISearchable
    ? SK
    : never;

type ValuesOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type SearchableServiceKey = Exclude<
    ValuesOf<{ [SK in ServiceKey]: IsSearchable<SK> }>,
    never
>;
```

but it's kind of a mouthful with the detour through mapping a key to its own type or `never` to express a predicate. Is there a simpler way to express this in TypeScript?

Comment: You don't have to exclude `never` from a union (it is already eliminated in unions).  Otherwise what you've done is fine with the possible exception of having intermediate types you won't use.  I usually define `type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]` and then you'd have `type SearchableServiceKey = KeysMatching<IAllServices, {search(q: string): any}>`.
`

Comment: @jcalz Just found the same thing while poking at the utility-types library. It's definitely an improvement so if you answerify it I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got is correct, and the only strictly unnecessary part is where you manually try to remove `never` types as constituents of a union.  The compiler already automatically eliminates `never` from unions:

```
type Foo = never | string | never | number | never | boolean | never;
// IntelliSense shows: type Foo = string | number | boolean;
```

The only other thing I'd suggest is that you don't need to give type alias names to all the intermediate steps of your type if you're not going to reuse them.  The idea of "give me the keys of an object type `T` whose properties are assignable to a value type `V`" comes up often enough that I usually define the following type alias:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> =
    { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

And then you can derive the type you're looking for as

```
type SearchableServiceKey = 
    KeysMatching<IAllServices, {search(q: string): any}>;
// IntelliSense shows: type SearchableServiceKey = "foo"
```

[Playgound link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20KeysMatching%3CT%2C%20V%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D-%3F%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20V%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IFooService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aaa()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20search(query%3A%20string)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IBarService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bbb()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IAllServices%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20IFooService%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20IBarService%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SearchableServiceKey%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20KeysMatching%3CIAllServices%2C%20%7B%20search(q%3A%20string)%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20IntelliSense%20shows%3A%20type%20SearchableServiceKey%20%3D%20%22foo%22)

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!